# Can we open "Launch Python Script from Insert Trigger"?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[Launching a python script from an insert trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54989/launching-a-python-script-from-an-insert-trigger)

As you can see, OP is asking for coding specifics as they do not know how to do this. I really don't see how "How can you make a python script execute when a table is updated?" is too broad. The question OP is asking isn't even opinion based. It's very technical.

It might be controversial, but it shouldn't be closed as too broad or opinion based because of this.

Answer (score 7):

As I write this, the question has three of the five reopen votes needed to reopen. I don't personally feel strongly enough about it to cast my own 'vote'.

It also has two of the three delete votes needed for deletion. I do feel strongly enough about keeping the question and it's answer around (even if closed) to reverse that deletion should it occur.

**Note:** the OP did re-ask the question as suggested in a comment. That question was answered here, then migrated to Stack Overflow: [How do I create a Python CLR procedure in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20584374/440595) where it was edited to be more correct.

The final state of the Q & A here should probably contain a  more permanent link to that SO question. (It's too old now to migrate the original question to Stack Overflow to close as a duplicate without staff intervention). The question probably has independent value on this site anyway.

---

**Update:** The question has now been reopened by user voting, and the delete votes cleared.